# magento 2 update Total Paid after payment manually

Tags: magento2

> how can I update the **total paid** amount Magento 2 sales order? invoice is already generated  and
>   **generate the credit memo button**.

I want to like total due to converting to total paid

[image]

Comment: Generate the invoice, if you want to update it by programmatically then create invoice programmatically, it will update total paid amount.
(https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-programmatically-create-invoice-in-magento2/)

Comment: @NalinSavaliya worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If invoice is created with 'Not capture' mode

[image]

then you have this due amount

[image]

so you want to mark it as paid manually then click this 'capture' option by opening invoice

[image]

so that order is updated with Total Paid
[image]